# (Angular 2+) Using ng-content in *ngFor, cannot access the loop variables

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, ng-template

How can I transclude/project into a slot that is within a loop, and have the projected content able to access the loop variables?

Say I have a base component with the following

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of items">
    <td>{{data.title}}</td>
    <ng-content select="[slot]"></ng-content>
</tr>
```

And a child component that uses the transclusion slot "slot"

```
<parent [items]="items"> 
    <ng-container slot>
        <td>{{data.category}}</td>
        <td>{{data.number}}</td>
    </ng-container>
</parent>
```

The HTML I'd like generated is

```
<tr>
    <td>{{data.title}}</td>
    <td>{{data.category}}</td>
    <td>{{data.number}}</td>
</tr>
```

But what actually happens is that "data" is not defined in the child component, which makes sense. Is there any way I can get it to work like this?

Comment: Where are you calling the *child component*?

Comment: @developer033 I'm calling the child component in another component. So `<child-component></child-component>`


The child component grabs the data that goes into the item via xhr and passes it into the parent like this:

    <parent [items]="items">
        <ng-container slot>
            <td>{{data.category}}</td>
            <td>{{data.number}}</td>
        </ng-container>
    </parent>

Comment: Exactly right. I'm trying to get "data" - the loop variable into the child component like you would normally in twig for example

Comment: it sounds like you want this: https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content#multi-slot-content-projection

Comment: @RudolfOlah I've seen that tutorial. I'm using the multi-slot transclusion/projection, but the issue here is that I'm using a slot which is in a loop.

Comment: slot is not a member of data, how could you select a multi-slot?

Comment: slot is defined as a transclusion slot in the base component `<ng-content select="[slot]"></ng-content>`

Answer (score 3):

Using `TemplateRef` it is possible to declare template variables acting between two components declaratively, on templates level. The following solution does not fully match your "slot" infrastructure but could be useful to further investigation.

**list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, ContentChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'list',
  template: `
    <tr class="box" *ngFor="let data of items">
      <td>{{data.title}}</td>
      <ng-template
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: data }">
      </ng-template>
    </tr>`
})
export class ListComponent {
  @Input() items;
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef;
  constructor() { }
}
```

**wrapper.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ContentChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper',
  template: `
    <table>
      <list [items]="items">
        <ng-template let-data>
          <td>{{data.category}}</td>
          <td>{{data.number}}</td>
        </ng-template>
      </list>
    </table>`
})
export class WrapperComponent {
  items = [
    { title: 'T1', category: 'C1', number: 'N1' },
    { title: 'T2', category: 'C2', number: 'N2' },
    { title: 'T3', category: 'C3', number: 'N3' }
  ];
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef;
  constructor() { }
}
```

I also created a [Plunker demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/5lgEgR/)...

Answer (score 0):

@dhilt's answer is a good implementation, but I have a way to make it useful for named slots as well as single slots:

```
// list.component.ts
import { Component, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'list',
  template: `
    <tr class="box" *ngFor="let data of items">
      <td>{{data.title}}</td>
      <ng-template
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: data }">
      </ng-template>
    </tr>`
})
export class ListComponent<T extends {title: any}> {
  @Input() items: T[];
  @Input() template: TemplateRef<{$implicit: T}>;
  constructor() { }
}
```

```
// wrapper.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper',
  template: `
    <table>
      <list [items]="items" [template]="itemTemplate"></list>
      <ng-template #itemTemplate let-data>
        <td>{{data.category}}</td>
        <td>{{data.number}}</td>
      </ng-template>
    </table>`
})
export class WrapperComponent {
  items = [
    { title: 'T1', category: 'C1', number: 'N1' },
    { title: 'T2', category: 'C2', number: 'N2' },
    { title: 'T3', category: 'C3', number: 'N3' }
  ];
  constructor() { }
}
```

Here is the API docs for [`*ngTemplateOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet). Even other directives like [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) use templates in that manner.